# A word to describe making something like something else

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Here's my scenario.  I am creating something that basically copies data and places under another "key value".

Ex:  Original Values

```
Key     Value1   Value2  Value3
 A        A1        2      A54
 B        B3        4      B68
 C        C5        23     C11
```

New Values

```
Key     Value1   Value2  Value3
 A        A1        2      A54
 B        B1        2      B54
 C        C5        23     C11
```

Then I will make B look like `B     B1   2` After it is done. Essentially copying rows but keeping the Key values.

I was going to call it "Mirror Data", but I'm not sure if that makes sense.  I ruled out "Copy Data" because it isn't a true copy.

I would like to know if "Mirror" would be a good description or if there a better descriptive word I could use for this action.

Comment: This is unclear. Are you copying a row and then modifying it? 'copy' may be better than 'mirror'; the latter implies it is identical to the source and will never be changed. 'copy' would allow further modifications.

Comment: @Mitch Sorry for it being unclear.  Much of the data is prefixed with whatever the key is.  So basically I'll be taking all the data and moving it into a new key while retaining that keys prefix for all the new data under it. I hope this makes a little more sense!

Comment: Are you creating a new row or a new column? Give an explicit example of before and after. Your example is static as it stands, I don't know what is old and what is new.

Comment: @Mitch I edited my original example.  To show you how B now looks like A but keeps its' prefix in the columns it has a prefix.  Let me know if I can explain anything better! Thanks.

Comment: Replicated or cloned?

Comment: Duplicated data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Transposed Data**

> Cause (two or more things) to exchange places.

[Transpose](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transpose)

Answer (score 0):

**Repositioned Data**

> Place in a different position; adjust or alter the position of.

[Reposition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reposition)